# Rails little loop error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a job model which has_many offers, User could accept or reject these offers, but how can I do that when User accept an offer, the more offers cannot be created? I try to do this in that way, it works but it duplicates input boxes. So what I'm doing wrong or how can I do it in another way?

```
#show.html.haml
- if @job.offers.blank?
  = render 'offers/form'

- @job.offers.each do |f|
  - if @job.offers.find(f).status == false || @job.offers.find(f).status == nil 
    = render 'offers/form'
  - else
    cannot do that

 #offers/_form.html.haml
 = simple_form_for([@job, @job.offers.build]) do |f|
   = f.input :pirce_offer
   = f.button :submit
```

Comment: When you iterate over `@job.offers`, each `f` in that loop is an `offer`.  (Please use descriptive variable names, eg "offer", it makes things so much more readable).  You then do `if @job.offers.find(f).status` - this is very odd.  Why are you looking it up again?  Why not just say `if f.status == false`?  Also, you can use `if f.status.blank?` instead of testing whether it's equal to false or nil.

Comment: Ohh that's right. But when I test `f.status == false || f.status == nil || f.status.blank?` , it doesn't work, I mean the `form` is not rendering, when `status.blank?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to equate yourself with [scoping in programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)); whenever you create a "block" in Ruby, it's essentially like invoking a function, with [its own local scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope):

```
- @job.offers.each do |f|
  - if f.status == false || f.status == nil 
    = render 'offers/form'
  - else
    cannot do that
```

As an aside to this, I don't get the purpose of calling a form that builds a new offer?

You're looping through an offer of a job, using the *status* conditional to determine whether the user should create an offer or not.... yet, surely if the offer *exists*, the user has already posted an offer?

Also, you're using a completely fresh set of data for the form:

```
 = simple_form_for([@job, @job.offers.build]) do |f|
   = f.input :pirce_offer
   = f.button :submit
```

<s>Shouldn't you be using something like the following:</s>

```
 = simple_form_for([@job, f]) do |f|
   = f.input :pirce_offer
   = f.button :submit
```

Okay I get it -- you have a sort of "auction" system where offers are accepted/declined. This would give you the ability to make a new offer if the previous was rejected........... it's still sketchy as hell.

---

> how can I do that when User accept an offer, the more offers cannot be created

You'll need to use some validation in your view and model.

Something like this:

```
#app/models/offer.rb
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :job, message: "Only one offer per job" }
end
```

---

I could create a much more complete answer if you describe how you want the jobs/offers to work.

Comment: Thank you, I want to do that: User(Seller) can create `job`, users(Buyers) of this job could create `offers` and when Seller accepts `offer`, the ability of making new `offers` to this `job` is blocked.